# How to add element in a selected column of a numpy array of shape (n,m)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, data-science, numpy-ndarray

I have a array X = np.random.randn(399,2).
I want to add 1 in each element of first column. How can I get my desired result?
After adding the shape of X should remain same as before means X.shape = (399,2).

Answer (score 1):

You want to slice the array and make the required changes to the first column:

```
X = np.random.randn(3,3)
print("Before Adding", X, sep="\n")
X[:, 0] += 1
print("After Adding", X, sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
Before Adding:
[[-0.23859111  1.76891702  1.3049423 ]
[ 0.12142094  1.80814525 -0.28181661]
[ 2.17874407  1.07034109 -0.17833234]]
After Adding:
[[ 0.76140889  1.76891702  1.3049423 ]
[ 1.12142094  1.80814525 -0.28181661]
[ 3.17874407  1.07034109 -0.17833234]]
```

The `:` for slicing in the first axis tells it to look at all rows, the `0` for the second access tells it to only look at the first element along that axis, i.e. the first column. Then you can just add 1 to it.

Read more about [NumPy Array Slicing](https://www.w3schools.com/python/numpy/numpy_array_slicing.asp).

Also NOTE: A simple google search would have given you the answer. SO community generally does not appreciate such lack of effort / research before asking questions. Keep that in mind next time.

Comment: I did the same but didn't get the desired result. Before posting this question here I searched for it. I also discussed with my friend.

Comment: @ArunKumar2403 I have added a detailed example to show the output. It is doing exactly what you described in the question. If I have misinterpreted your question, add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question.